# ArrayAdapter getView not called

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter`, and even though my `getCount` method is called, (and I'm returning my array's count, in the sample case, that count is 181) my `getView` is not called. This started today and it seems to be happening randomly. Sometimes, it just does get called and displays perfectly. Sometimes, after loading the data, it just stays blank. Here is a few things:

- I've put a breakpoint in `getCount` and it returns a positive number.
- I've set the background color of my list to some color, and it's displayed perfectly, filling the screen with it's background color. So no layout issues.
- I've put a breakpoint in `setAdapter` method, it's getting called normally, on the UI thread. (if this wasn't called, `getCount` wouldn't have been called anyway)

It's interesting that this is not always happening. I've restarted my device (Galaxy S3, if helps) a few minutes ago and the problem went away, but now, while I'm writing this questions, it came back. I've checked my network connection, no issues (I'm getting the array of items successfully anyway). I've seen many questions about this specific issue but none of them solved my problem. I'm on ICS if it helps.

Here is my constructor:

```
protected List<Map<String, Object>> objects;
protected Map<String, Object> user;

public FeedAdapter(Context context, List<Map<String, Object>> objects, Map<String, Object> attachedUser) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
    this.user = attachedUser;
}
```

And I'm calling this explicitly on the UI thread from the data load handler (`dataSource` is valid with many items):

```
 dataSource = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) task.getResult();
 FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), dataSource, getUser());
 ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
 list.setOnItemClickListener(self);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What could cause the problem?

Comment: Are you passing data to super class properly in constructor by calling super()? And there is no need to override getCount if you are using `ArrayAdapter`.Also you can try extending `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdaper`

Comment: @AbhishekV I've added my constructor code. I think it's right, but have a look.

Comment: Just checking, after data is loaded from network are you calling notifydatasetchanged?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Constructor seems to be proper.

Comment: @prashant I'm already creating the adapter with loaded data after the data is loaded. (yeah I know, maybe not the best pattern, but anyway)

Comment: In you code above , is this line , blocking or non blocking 
 dataSource = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) task.getResult();

What i mean is if above line is asynchronous, then the other part of the code can get executed before the task.getResult() returns all data.

Comment: @prashant it's synchronous. it's on the same block,  `getResult` should return before I create the adapter. but as I said, it's already at the completion handler of data task, dataSource is valid.

Answer (score 1):

First, please check your return in getCount(), make sure you have returned your data(List,ArrayList 's size) in getCount

Second, make sure any other view TextView,View may not overlap to your ListView, if it is not, getView cannot render or bind data to ListContent of your ListView.So in your CustomAdapter you have Data(List,ArrayList) and that is why getView() not called.

I hope this will help you to work.

Answer (score -1):

Change the Layout(ListView) height,Width to match parent.